# Connecting AT motherboard to ATX PSU

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

I have an old PC with a dead PSU. I got a new PSU with ATX. How can I power the old AT PC with the ATX power supply? I have proprietary software that can't be run on newer PCs.

Comment: The motherboard usually is not the deciding factor for why you need to run old software, unless you rely on a specific port it has, such as COM1, etc. I don't think AT and ATX power supply are interchangable.

Comment: I need to get data off a floppy. It is 16 bit software. @LPChip

Comment: If the program runs under DOS, you can run it under Dosbox in any computer. If it runs under Windows, you can use a VM and install that windows inside. Windows 3.11 can be installed inside Dosbox too and most likely Windows 95 can too. See: https://www.howtogeek.com/230359/how-to-install-windows-3.1-in-dosbox-set-up-drivers-and-play-16-bit-games/

Comment: @LPChip It is a graphical app. When trying to install on a newer device it says it's not the corret hardware.

Comment: But what OS does it require? DOS or Windows?

Comment: @LPChip Windows 3.1

Comment: You can use Dosbox and install Windows 3.1 in it, and it should work because DosBox does proper emulation. See the link in my earlier comment for a tutorial.

Comment: In order to setup a dosbox and windows 3.1 installation, you are many hours into configuration state. Your reponse was sooner which indicates that you did not try installing windows 3.1 inside a dosbox installation, but just tried the software on a modern windows.

Answer (score 2):

You can purchase an ATX to AT PSU adapter.  Here is a Google [search](http://atx%20to%20at%20power%20supply%20adapter).

[image]